# Usage of PLD instruction

Tags: arm, cpu-cache, mmu, cortex-a8

I have some doubts regarding the usage of PLD instruction in ARM cortex A8. As I am using the instruction inside loop, there is a possibility of out of bound memory access. My doubt is that whether that would cause a segmentation fault or not. I read in the [ARM manual which states that](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0338g/Chdfgbii.html)

> Because a PLD instruction is handled as any other load instruction by all levels of cache, the PLD instruction follows standard data-dependency rules and eviction procedures. During any stage of PLD execution, the PLD instruction is ignored in case of an address translation fault, a cache hit, or an abort.

So, if an out of bound memory access is made, the corresponding PLD instruction is ignored or not is my doubt.

Comment: +1: Great question, I have been wondering about this myself but never bothered to check it up.

Comment: Thanks for the question @Rugger I myself have faced this few years back. The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PLD instruction doesn't create segmentation fault. In case PLD asks memory system to reach for a non existing memory area, it is ignored.

From ARM ARM

> > The Preload instructions are hints, and so implementations can treat them as NOPs without affecting the functional
> >     behavior of the device. **The instructions do not generate synchronous Data Abort exceptions**, but the memory system
> >     operations might, under exceptional circumstances, generate asynchronous aborts.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > However, a memory operation performed as a result of one of these memory system
> >     hints might trigger an asynchronous event, so influencing the execution of the processor. Examples of the
> >     asynchronous events that might be triggered are asynchronous aborts and interrupts.